# Getting the value of a 'ctx' object of an AST node

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a config file, config.py, and I'm trying to read the value of an attribute without using `importlib.import_module()` (or `imp.load_source()`).

So, I did this:

```
# trying to just get the attribute 'comment' from the file

import ast
fd = open('config.py')
root = ast.parse(fd.read())
names = list(node for node in ast.walk(root) if isinstance(node, ast.Name) and node.id == 'comment')
print(names)
# [<_ast.Name object at 0x7fcb999048d0>]
print(names[0])
# <_ast.Name object at 0x7fcb999048d0>
print(names[0].id)
# 'comment'
print(names[0].ctx)
# <_ast.Store object at 0x7fcb9b9acbd0>
print(names[0].lineno)
# 12
print(names[0].ctx)
# <_ast.Store object at 0x7f19db3f1c10>
dir(names[0].ctx)
# ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
# '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', 
# '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
# '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', '_fields']
```

The file (config.py) has this on line 12:

```
comment = "qos sample run"
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to get this value (`"qos sample run"`) in code. I could read the file and get line 12 but I'm guessing that the value is stored somewhere in the ctx object but I just can't figure out where.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just `import config`? What you're trying to do is what Python already does for you when it imports a module or runs any code whatsoever.

Comment: In my context, there are 100s of such config files that I need to read to get to an attribute. I've noticed that importing or even "imp.load_source"ing is noticeably slow. I'm using the attribute's value to populate a column of an HTML table (which makes the table entry unique). So, I do have working code using imp.load_source() that works but is noticeably slower than using the ast module to read the attribute. I now use the node.id, node.lineno to get the value by reading the line from the file (MUCH faster) but I was hoping that the node.ctx can be somehow interrogated to get what I want

Comment: I think you may be looking for an `Assign` node instead of `Name`. It'll give you both the target (`comment`) and the value (`"qos sample run"`).

Comment: @ForceBru, thank you. I finally dumped the entire tree and found that as well. So, looking for the Assign node does solve my problem.